# Hibernate @ElementCollection size / null validation always fails

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I'm trying to set up an element collection for my latest spring boot project but I am having issues with the validation.

I want to make sure there is at least one value in the set.

I have tried:

```
@Size(min = 1)
@NotEmpty
@NotNull
```

But every time the validation fails. Even if I try and save a set with one or more items in it.

Here is the current code of the property in my entity.

```
@ElementCollection(targetClass=Integer.class, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@CollectionTable(name="campaign_publisher", joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="campaign_id"))
@Column(name="publisher_id", nullable = false)
private Set<Integer> publishers = new HashSet<>();
```

The strange thing is that I have created unit tests for this validation and they work fine. This was done by getting a validator from the validator factory. For example:

```
ValidatorFactory factory = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory()
validator                = factory.getValidator()

...

Set<ConstraintViolation<Campaign>> constraintViolations = validator.validate(campaign)
```

But when I send the entity to CrudRepository to be saved thats when the validation fails.

Also if I remove the validation on this property and run an integration test the data is saved correctly.

If you need anymore info let me know and I will provide it.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/javax.validation/validation-api/1.0.0.GA/javax/validation/constraints/Size.java it shoudl work. At least it states **Supported types are:
String (string length is evaludated)
Collection (collection size is evaluated)**. Alternatively you can write custom annotation

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I did actually try writing a custom annotation on the entity but I was running into a weird issue where the publishers property was null. So I debugged and found that just before I called the method to save the data, the publishers existed. But when it goes into the custom validation class it was null. I also noticed that the entity object in the custom validation is not the same one that was passed into the save method (the hashcodes are different).

Comment: Could be side effect of proxy. Try to move the @Size from field to getter or try to "unproxy" the entity before validation.

Comment: I did try @Size on the getter but got the same. Thanks for the suggestion, i'll give it a try.